# Privacy Policy URL for instagram

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, privacy

I'm trying to register new `Client ID` on Instagram, for give API.

But I don't know how can I fill `Privacy Policy URL`. Please guide me.

Answer (score 5):

Here is format [@ http://www.grabapp.co/legal/privacypolicy.html](http://www.grabapp.co/legal/privacypolicy.html) 
you can update content of your app privacy Policy.  use this as reference only.

Answer (score 1):

It is a url where the  "Privacy Policy" of your application can be found.

Comment: hi,thanks for answer, where is this url?Should I create on my site?

Comment: Because your application will have access to private data, you have to write a  "Privacy Policy" on your site which explains what you will do with this private information.Instagram asks for the url so that they may verify the kind of usage you plan to do with this sensible data.